# WPF UI Automation with Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, caliburn.micro, white-framework

I am attempting to write some UI automation tests for a WPF application that is using [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com) and [White](http://white.codeplex.com/). I am using CM's builtin conventions to bind my controls to the view model's properties and methods. I am also using `Conductor` classes so that I may have multiple views visible on a single screen. This generally means that multiple controls on a screen can end up having the same `x:Name` value. It will just get bound to a different view model. A good idea of what I am trying to do can be seen in the [HelloScreens sample application that comes with CM](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ff8f27cb3fb0#).

The problem that I am running in to is that I will have multiple XAML elements with the same `x:Name` attribute so that CM can handle all of the binding work for me. This unfortunately means that multiple `UIItem` objects will have the same UI Automation ID. The only way I have found to get, for instance, different `TextBlock` elements with `x:Name="DisplayName"` is to make a call such as the following:

```
SearchCriteria criteria = SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("DisplayName").AndIndex(1);
WPFLabel label = myWindow.Get<WPFLabel>(criteria);
```

This means my tests need to know the exact order that different controls are placed on the screen, which seems very brittle. I can see my tests all breaking just by adding another view model.

- Is there a way to specify the Automation ID other than using the `x:Name` attribute?
- Would this be easier if I used the UI Automation framework directly instead of using White?
- Or, do I really have to forego CM's convention based binding and give everyting unique `x:Name` values and bind them by hand?

**UPDATED**

To clarify what I mean by having multiple views visible at once, here is my general layout. I have my `ShellViewModel` which I derive from `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`. Then my view has an `ItemsControl` that is bound to the shell view model's `Items` property. Each item template shows a button that is meant to load that specific `IScreen` into a `ContentControl` that is on the shell's view. So, If I try to look for an element with `x:Name="DisplayName"`, I have the label on the shell view, the label on the button in the `ItemsControl` as well as a label inside of the `ContentControl`.

Comment: When you say you have multiple views visible on a single screen, what conductor type are you using?  Conductor<T> or Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive etc?

Comment: I've updated the post to clarify my exact setup. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the AutomationId by default comes from the x:Name attribute, you can override it by setting [AutomationProperties.AutomationId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.automationid.aspx).

Comment: Wow. This would be an even better solution yet. I hadn't noticed there was an attached property in WPF for this. I'll give this a shot tonight.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was able to maintain CM's default conventions, and give the controls I wanted to test meaningful identifiers for testing. Thanks Samuel.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to alter the `BindProperties` and `BindActions` delegates on the `ViewModelBinder` type to work with control names whose names are altered based on the view in which they belong.

For example, you could optionally add the view name as a prefix to each control that is likely to have duplicate names in other views.  So `DisplayName` could become `ListViewDisplayName`, and `ContentViewDisplayName`.

Any text from the control name up to and including the word 'View' could be stripped to form the clean control name before continuing processing the control.

Comment: <forehead smack> Of course, if the conventions don't work, then change the conventions. That will actually solve my problem quite effectively. Thanks for the great idea.